# SSL & mixed content and streaming video over https

Tags: html, ssl, video-streaming, http-streaming

I have a business web app which is served using SSL only. One of the pages has a video served from screencast.com. Screencast.com doesn't seem to support SSL and the video is streamed using http and therefore I get a mixed content IE warning.

The video is showing using a lightbox type window using an iFrame.

Are there any workarounds or solutions to avoid the warning? Other than serving the page without SSL.

I might have to switch from screencast.com. Any video streaming hosts which support streaming over SSL and support iPads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Lightbox where the html is on the same page, I opted to launch another browser window and made it look like a lightbox popup as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could serve the video yourself but I am not sure that this worth the trouble.

One option would be to use http://sproutvideo.com/features - they can serve via SSL and support among other things iPad etc. (not affiliated, not even a customer)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting sproutvideo.com. I haven't checked it out. I used my workaround in my answer.